dovecot LMTP: only allow certain users
I only want mail to be delivered to certain users, with all other users unable to receive email. I've been looking at Dovecot's documentation for hours, though, and I can't figure it out.
All I want is an option like
lmtp_allow_users = alice bob

or something like that.
